# Passing a list which whose elements are objects in Android JAVA

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to pass this [{'name','abc'},{'call','cdf'}] as a JSON response in JAVA android. This can be done in JSON javascript using JSON.stringify. How to achieve it in android?

Comment: If you have an array of objects and you want to convert to Json, then you can use the Gson library and the mehotd .toJson, for example, Gson().toJson(yourObject), and convert the  Json to object: Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, yourArrayType)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the app/build.gradle
2. Add the Gson library in dependencies

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'  //change to the latest version
}
```

3. Add a class for object that you want to parse json string. for example I define User class:

```
public class User 
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
     
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

4. Import Gson library in class that you want to use this library:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

5. Parse json array with the following code:

```
String userJson = "[{'name': 'Oliver','id': 1}, "
                + "{'name': 'Jack','id':2}, "
                + "{'name': 'Harry','id': 3}]";
         
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
 
User[] userArray = gson.fromJson(userJson, User[].class);  
 
for(User user : userArray) {
    System.out.println(user);
}
```

Thank you :)